# Ejecutar servicio de red al arranque en Servidor RHEL 7

Tags: linux, shell, servidor, unix

Estoy trabajando con el servidor RHEL 7 (MAIPO), pero tengo el problema de que al reiniciarse el mismo, la red no levanta automáticamente y tengo que estar apretando el botón para iniciar la red desde la GUI.

Entiendo que lo que sucede es que el servicio  de red no esta iniciando al arranque del sistema. Lo he intentado solucionar con los comandos:

```
chkconfig network on
systemctl enable network.service
systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
```

Cuando ejecuto este último comando sí se nota que ha cambiado el ENABLE y el DISABLE cuando ejecuto el comando:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager.service
```

pero nada cambia con systemctl y network.service, en este caso siempre está en DISABLE. Entendía que esta gestión de servicios se estaba ahora canalizando por systemctl, pero observo que aun está vivo chkconfig. Eso me confunde porque no sé qué servicios van por acá o por allá, de hecho, cuando ejecuto

```
systemctl enable network.service
```

el comando me arroja este mensaje:

> network.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
>   Executing /sbin/chkconfig network on

Espero puedan darme una mano.

Comment: Para arrancar la red de forma manual como lo haces ?

Comment: accedo al servidor de forma gráfica en el propio servidor, y allí activo la red con simples clicks. Luego de hacer eso, me voy a mi pc cliente y ya puedo acceder al servidor por ssh telnet, etc.

Comment: si haces un systemctl start NetworkManager no te va?

Comment: la idea es que yo estoy en un pc cliente, y que desde aca por ejemplo pueda ejecutar "init 6" para reiniciar el servidor, esperar un tiempo a que se reinicie el servidor y establecer una conexion ssh desde mi cliente, todo sin tener que moverme del computador cliente. El comando que me comentas @IgnacioBelmonte es para iniciar la red estando dentro del servidor por consola, a los efectos que menciono, no me sirve porque al reiniciar el servidor, ya entonces desde el cliente no tengo accesos al mismo porque la red del servidor no levanta sola.

Comment: ¿Has probado a ejecutar el comando `chkconfig network on` ?

Comment: Hola @IgnacioBelmonte, por favor lee [answer]. Stack Overflow no funciona como un foro y estás publicando/borrando respuestas que deberían ser comentarios (comprendo que aún no tienes puntos para comentar en todas las publicaciones), lo cual puede hacer que el sistema te bloquee y te impida escribir respuestas. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento en general. Un saludo.

Comment: si @IgnacioBelmonte ya probe con ese comando, ademas como ya comente, el comando "systemctl enable network.service" me redirecciona al comando "chkconfig network on"

Answer (score 0):

**Cordial saludo:**

Para configurar el arranque automático de la interfaz del red, puedes hacerlo modificando la variable **ONBOOT** que se encuentra en el directorio /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[nombre_interfaz_de_red], puedes revisar tu interfaz de red desde la terminal con el comando **ip addr** por ejemplo para mi caso es:

[image: Revision interfaces de red mediante el comando **ip addr**]

En mi caso mi interfaz de red es eth0, por lo tanto debo editar el archivo
**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0** y poner la variable **ONBOOT=yes**

[image: archivo de configuración interfaz de red]

Una vez se realiza el procedimiento, la próxima vez que se inicie el sistema operativo, la interfaz de red estará arriba.